# Pass user input to 'by' in data.table and the formula in reshape - r

Tags: r, data.table, reshape

Below is an example of what I want to do. `eval(substitute(*))` works well, as shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24361146/pass-variables-and-names-to-data-table-function), but makes the code a bit harder to read. I was wondering if there is anything better I am not aware of.

I want to be able to choose the row and column variables of the table (at the end).
So, if I have

```
input.col <- 'Gender'
input.row <- 'Region'
```

I want to be able to pass these arguments to the data table instead of `Region` and `Gender` being used as below.

```
library(data.table)
library(reshape)
set.seed(5)
DT <- data.table(Region = sample(x = c('Asia', 'Americas', 'Africa', 'Europe', 'Oceania'), size = 200, replace = T), Weight = runif(n = 200, min = 1, max = 5), Age = round(x = 10*rexp(n = 200, rate = 1), digits = 0), Gender = sample(x = c('Male', 'Female', 'Gender diverse'), size = 200, replace = T, prob = c(0.49, 0.49, 0.02)))
cast(data = DT[, sum(Weight), .(Region, Gender)], formula = Region~Gender, fun.aggregate = sum, value = 'V1')
```

I want to get to the following table

```
Region   Female Gender diverse     Male
1   Africa 32.95019       3.222125 77.50863
2 Americas 49.12787       0.000000 84.97214
3     Asia 41.04879       0.000000 55.43294
4   Europe 45.39469       4.296767 47.76714
5  Oceania 65.89198       1.439075 72.27496
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here are some possibilities.  Except for (3) they only use data.table.  All the approaches perform aggregation and reshaping in one operation so there is no need to use `by` in the first place.  If you really did want to use `by` for some reason anyways then this would work:

```
cast(data = DT[, sum(Weight), by = c(input.row, input.col)], 
     formula = paste(input.row, "~", input.col), fun.aggregate = sum, value = 'V1')
```

**1) data.table::dcast**

```
dcast(DT, paste(input.row, "~", input.col), sum, value.var = "Weight")
```

giving:

```
     Region   Female Gender diverse     Male
1:   Africa 32.95019       3.222125 77.50863
2: Americas 49.12787       0.000000 84.97214
3:     Asia 41.04879       0.000000 55.43294
4:   Europe 45.39469       4.296767 47.76714
5:  Oceania 65.89198       1.439075 72.27496
```

**2) xtabs** `xtabs` is in the base of R:

```
fo <- sprintf("Weight ~ %s + %s", input.row, input.col)
xtabs(fo, DT)
```

giving:

```
          Gender
Region        Female Gender diverse      Male
  Africa   32.950187       3.222125 77.508626
  Americas 49.127873       0.000000 84.972137
  Asia     41.048787       0.000000 55.432941
  Europe   45.394693       4.296767 47.767138
  Oceania  65.891983       1.439075 72.274955
```

**3) reshape::cast**  We will use the reshape package because the question does but note that it has been superceded by the reshape2 package and in reshape2 one would use `dcast`; however, `dcast` is also implemented in data.table as per (1).

```
cast(DT, paste(input.row, "~", input.col), sum, value = "Weight")
```

giving:

```
    Region   Female Gender diverse     Male
1   Africa 32.95019       3.222125 77.50863
2 Americas 49.12787       0.000000 84.97214
3     Asia 41.04879       0.000000 55.43294
4   Europe 45.39469       4.296767 47.76714
5  Oceania 65.89198       1.439075 72.27496
```

**4) tapply**

```
tapply(DT$Weight, as.list(DT)[c(input.row, input.col)], sum, default = 0)
```

giving:

```
          Gender
Region       Female Gender diverse     Male
  Africa   32.95019       3.222125 77.50863
  Americas 49.12787       0.000000 84.97214
  Asia     41.04879       0.000000 55.43294
  Europe   45.39469       4.296767 47.76714
  Oceania  65.89198       1.439075 72.27496
```

Comment: This is a great list. It's length is also proportional to my ignorance! Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

You can use `get` and then rename the variables which can be further used in the formula:

```
input.col <- 'Gender'
input.row <- 'Region'

dt <- cast(data = DT[, sum(Weight), .(row = get(input.row), col = get(input.col))], 
#                                     ^^^   ^^^             ^^^   ^^^  
           formula = row ~ col, fun.aggregate = sum, value = 'V1')

dt
#       row   Female Gender diverse     Male
#1   Africa 32.95019       3.222125 77.50863
#2 Americas 49.12787       0.000000 84.97214
#3     Asia 41.04879       0.000000 55.43294
#4   Europe 45.39469       4.296767 47.76714
#5  Oceania 65.89198       1.439075 72.27496
```